# Windows 11 Blocking Linux Distro Installation HP Pavillian 500

Tags: boot, usb, linux-mint, rufus, hp

Followed all pertinent steps, for proper install:

1. Created USB ISO Linuxmint-21.3-mate-64bit (Rufus).
2. UEFI settings, safe boot disabled, BIOS set up to choose USB.
3. At restart, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>, choose USB device and USB mint device lights up. Should boot.
4. At this stage it always boots back to Windows 11.

So question is how do I stop Windows 11 from interfering with my dual boot process? I have a disc set aside for my install when I get to that point.

Comment: 1. Modern Linux can and should be installed *with* Safe Boot enabled. 2. If you have Fast Startup or Quick Boot enabled, it prevents the PC from fully rebooting. Disable in BIOS/UEFI. 3. Perform a **complete** windows shutdown before installation, i.e., disable Hibernation: `powercfg -h off`  and fully shut down: `shutdown /s /t 0
`

Comment: ... or simply disable the Wibndows Fast Startup feature and shutdown normally. Windows 11 is NOT interfering with the ability to boot external media, it's a problem with the media (in Rufus prefer UEFI/GPT or use a failt proof tool like Balena Etcher), check integrity of your diownload and/or UEFI ("BIOS") settings.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the Mint 21.3 ISO being improperly mastered and using a broken symbolic link for its UEFI bootloader. See https://github.com/linuxmint/linuxmint/issues/622.

You have 3 solutions:

1. Wait for the next release of Mint to fix the issue (NB: You might be able to try the *Edge* version of Mint, that gets fixes earliers) and also make sure to set the partition scheme to GPT when creating the media if using Rufus 4.3.
2. Use *DD Mode* in Rufus when prompted.
3. Use Rufus 4.4, which was [just released](https://rufus.ie), that adds a **workaround** for this specific issue.